# Rails Ajax Not Updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

How do i update a portion of a page using Ajax in rails 2.3.8?

i am trying to make a calendar with buttons to go to next and previous months. At the click of the buttons i want the calendar to change without reloading the whole page.

On of my buttons to scroll through months look like this:

```
    <%= link_to_remote "<",:update=>'calendar',:url=>{:action=>'ajax_calendar',:month => (@date.beginning_of_month-1).strftime("%Y-%m")} %>
```

This is my main page where i have rendered the partial.

```
 index.html.erb
    <div id="calendar">
        <%= render :partial=>'calendar' %>
    </div>
```

when i tried to debug with firebug the ajax call is getting executed correctly and i am also getting the correct response from the server but the id 'calender' is not getting updated.

Can somebody please point out what i am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Added controller

```
def ajax_calendar
    @events = Event.all
    @date = params[:month] ? Date.parse(params[:month].gsub('-', '/')) : Date.today
    render :partial => 'calender'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting this error because of using both prototype and jquery together. removing jQuery solved this.

Answer (score 0):

I think rails wants the url parameter before update. Try switiching the order like this:

```
<%= link_to_remote "<", :url=>{:action=>'ajax_calendar',:month => (@date.beginning_of_month-1).strftime("%Y-%m")}, :update=>'calendar' %>
```

However, this probably isn't it. Your link_to_remote looks good, it's probably something in the controller. Could you show us your controller code for the action?